# Angular Reactive Form - Apply validators only on specific field of object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, angular-validation

I have a reactive form with a form array in it. When I init my form, I push some form controls with default values in my form array.

Here's the code:

```js
formValues?.tipsAndTricks?.forEach((tipAndTrick) => {
  this.tipsAndTricks.push(
    this.fb.control(
      { id: tipAndTrick.id, tip: tipAndTrick.tip },
      { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(25), Validators.maxLength(2000)], updateOn: 'change' }
    )
  )
})
```

The problem is that my validators are not working because they are applied to an object:

```
{ id: tipAndTrick.id, tip: tipAndTrick.tip }
```

My question is how can I apply these validators only on the `tip` field of this object?

Comment: Willian, a FormControl can store "what-ever": a number, a boolean, a Date, a string, an object, an array... If we use an input tag only can use a number, a boolean or an string (else we need use a custom form control). As Yong Shun, say, you probably want to create a FormGroup with two formControls inside instead of an unique Formcontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FormArray` contains objects, thus you should push `FormGroup` with `this.fb.group()` instead of `FormControl`.

While you can add the validator(s) to the field with:

```js
{ tip: ['value', [/* Validators */]] }
```

or

```js
{ tip: this.fb.control('value', [/* Validators */]) }
```

The complete code should be:

```js
formValues?.tipsAndTricks?.forEach((tipAndTrick) => {
  this.tipsAndTricks.push(
    this.fb.group(
      { 
        id: [tipAndTrick.id], 
        tip: [tipAndTrick.tip, [
          Validators.required, 
          Validators.minLength(25), 
          Validators.maxLength(2000)]
        ] 
      }
    )
  )
})
```

Comment: Whan I do this I get this error **control.registerOnChange is not a function**

Comment: Can you try to create a StackBlitz demo with the sample data for debugging? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9nfuwt?file=src%2Fmain.ts

You'll see **[Object object]** in each field because normally I have a custom **textarea** that sets only the **tip** as a value.

But this is enough to see the error in the console

Comment: I create a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmipd5?file=src/main.ts) based on your existing code. Probably this is what you need.

Comment: Ok I get it know, thank you very much !